# Passing Data via UITableViewController using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, crash, uitableview, parameter-passing

I create an app that using MFSideMenu. The SideMenu is an UITableViewController and I'd like to pass data from my SideMenu to the designated Controller that is child of an UINavigationController. So here is the code:

```
else if(indexPath.section==2 && indexPath.row==0){

    HotelListController *Hotel = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HotelList"];
    Hotel.MyCoordinate=self.MyCoordinate; //--> the line that causing crash!

    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:Hotel];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;

    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
}
```

Why is that the 3rd line above causing crash? Is that wrong to pass data like that? the crash log showing this.

```
0x17e8d85:  movl   16(%edx), %edx
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, adress=bla blabla)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether self.MyCoordinate is nil or not before assigning.

I think it gets released so causing such exception

Comment: thanks man! I forgot to check that, and yes it is nil. Solved!